# How can I filter conditionally grouped data in Yii2 GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a table with three columns, namely graduate students id (grad_id), qualification, and supervisor. The task is to find how many students each supervisor has for various qualifications (PhD, Masters, PGD, Other and Total). The problem is that after generating the table view I am unable to filter out a supervisor's name to see how many students he/she supervises for each of the various qualifications categories.

My GridView in the view looks like this:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $sup,
     'filterModel' => $searchModel,
       'columns' => [
 ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'supervisor',
        'total',
        'phd',
        'masters',
        'pgd',
        'other',
    ],
])
```

With the above, I am able to generate the table. But the filter does not change the contents of the table even though the page is refreshed and the page web url changes to something like (when I search for david): `.../index.php?SupervisionSearch%5Bsupervisor%5D=david&SupervisionSearch%5Btotal%5D=&SupervisionSearch%5Bphd%5D=&SupervisionSearch%5Bmasters%5D=&SupervisionSearch%5Bpgd%5D=&r=student%2Fgrad-admissions%2Fsupervision`

In the SupervisionSearch class I have tried:

```
public $supervisor;
public $phd;
public $masters;
public $pgd;
public $other;
public $total;

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['supervisor','phd', 'masters', 'pgd', 'other', 'total'], 'safe'],
            [['phd', 'masters', 'pgd', 'other', 'total'], 'number'],
            [['supervisor'], 'string'],
        ];
    }


  public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }


    public function search($params)
    {
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(["supervisor, sum(qualification = 'PhD') as phd", "sum(qualification = 'Masters') as masters", "sum(qualification = 'PGD') as pgd", "sum(qualification <> 'PhD' and qualification <> 'Masters' and qualification <> 'PGD')as other", "count(grad_id) as total"])
-> from('grad_students') 
-> where("supervisor <> ''")
-> orderBy('total desc')
-> groupBy('supervisor');

  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        $this->load($params);
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'supervisor', $this->supervisor]); 
   return $dataProvider;
    }
```

I need help on getting the filter to search out particular supervisor names and display the number of the students they supervise for each qualifications category. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You your search function 
You could use `andFilterWhere` instead of `where`

```
public function search($params)
{
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(["supervisor, sum(qualification = 'PhD') as phd", 
  "sum(qualification = 'Masters') as masters",
  "sum(qualification = 'PGD') as pgd", 
     "sum(qualification <> 'PhD' 
        and qualification <> 'Masters' 
        and qualification <> 'PGD') as other", "count(grad_id) as total"])
-> from('grad_students') 
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'supervisor', $this->supervisor])
-> orderBy('total desc')
-> groupBy('supervisor');
.....
```

and you should remove the declaration for the column in  model .. you shoul declare only the calculated  column alias so try comment `public $supervisor;`

otherwise your re declaration hidden (redefine) the original value and don't work

```
//public $supervisor;
public $phd;
public $masters;
public $pgd;
public $other;
public $total;
```

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge, I tried to use `andFilterWhere` instead of `where` as suggested but the filter still does not work.

Comment: answer  updated  .. try comment //public $supervisor; in your search model

Comment: Thanks once again, I commented `public $supervisor;` but still it did not work. However, I tried out a kind of work around that I am posting as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution by a kind of work around. I think the issue has to do with absence of a primary key in the original question. What I did now, I first created a view in the database, which also did not have a primary key. Then I used the view (instead of the original table) to generate a model with GII. Next, I put a primaryKey function in the model, and then used the GII CRUD to generate the required search model, whose search filter now worked perfectly well.
This is the code I used to generate the view (with mysql using phpmyadmin):

```
create view supervisor_count as select supervisor, sum(qualification = 'PhD') as phd, sum(qualification = 'Masters') as masters, sum(qualification = 'PGD') as pgd, sum(qualification <> 'PhD' and qualification <> 'Masters' and qualification <> 'PGD')as other, count(grad_id) as total from  grad_students where supervisor <> '' group by supervisor order by count(grad_id) desc
```

This is the code that I had to include in the SupervisorCount model to get the primary key:

```
public static function primaryKey(){
return 'supervisor';
}
```

The GII CRUD could not run without a primary key. So I used the above primaryKey function in the model. But when the CRUD was generated, at first, the link to the table `/index.php?r=student%2Fsupervisor-count%2Findex` did not work, throwing an error 
`Getting unknown property: app\modules\student\models\SupervisorCount::p`. I resolved this by re-running the model `SupervisorCount` generator on Gii, which removed the primaryKey function that I had put in the model. Thereafter, the link worked properly. The GridView using the generated `SupervisorCountSearch` model now has a filter that works on each of the columns (Supervisor, Phd, Masters, Pgd, Other, Total).

However, I am still wondering whether there could be a better solution, or a solution that uses the original table `gradstudents` for the model instead of the mysql generated `supervisor_count` view.